# JEST trying to test an async function. Received error Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function (34:15)

Tags: unit-testing, asynchronous, async-await, jestjs

Ok Here is my code:
**routes.test.js**

```
import cisProvider from "./cognito-provider";

test ('User' , () => {
    expect.assertions(1);

    let data = await xcisProvider.forgoPassword({
            ClientId: '2fpfiodf5ppsqg6tnndfnkl5r',
            UserName: 'naman.jain@xe.com'
        }
    );
    expect(data.code_delivery_details.DeliveryMedium).toEqual("EMAIL");
});
```

*And here is what function I am trying to access*

**cognito-provider.js**

```
class CognitoProvider {

constructor(config) {}

forgotPassword = params => {
    const { Username: username, ClientId: clientId } = params;

    return this.getHashedClientSecret(username, clientId)
      .then(clientSecretHash => {
        params = Object.assign(params, {
          SecretHash: clientSecretHash
        });

        return this.provider.forgotPassword(params).promise();
      });
  };
}

export default CognitoProvider;
```

I recieve the following error when perform the test run

**SyntaxError: routes.test.js: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function (34:15)**

The line it refers to is :

```
let data = await xcisProvider.forgoPassword({ ...
```

Comment: `test ('User', async () => { ...`

Comment: Yes this solved my issue. But now I am getting a new one :  
    /Users/namanjain/LoginAPI/login-api/src/routes.test.js:24
    import xcisProvider from "./xe-cognito-provider";
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module